# Memory Leak closure in UIAlertController

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, protocols, uialertcontroller

I have a memory leak in when setting up an `UIAlertController`, I have seen other threads talking about memory leaks in `UIAlertController`. But I could not figure out how to change my code so the memory leak goes away. I changed `itemSelected` from a function to a computed property, but it did not change anything.

```
 protocol TriggerUIAlertController: class where Self: UIView {
        var itemsForPresenting: [String] { get }
        var titleForCancel: String { get }
        var titleForAlertController: String { get }
        var itemSelected: Int? {get set}
    }

    extension TriggerUIAlertController {

         func triggerUIAlerController() {
            let alertList = UIAlertController(title: titleForAlertController, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let closure = { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                let index = alertList.actions.index(of: alert)
                guard index != nil else {
                    return
                }

                ///produces memory leak, idk why though -> has to be checked
                self.itemSelected = index!
            }
            for x in itemsForPresenting {
                alertList.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: x, style: .default, handler: closure))
            }
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertList,animated: true, completion: nil)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: titleForCancel, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertList.addAction(cancelAction)
        }
    }
```

Btw: Is it normal that instruments uses after a usage of around five minutes a total of 50gb ram?

Comment: Speaking of Instruments memory usage - 5gb would be normal, 50 is too much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a leak caused by UIAlertController but more generally by a "retain cycle", you can have that with every closure that contains reference to `self` or any variable created outside the closure.

You can avoid it by changing the "definition" of the closure:

```
  let closure = { [weak self, weak alertList] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        guard let self = self, let alertList = alertList, let index = alertList.actions.index(of: alert) else { return }               
            self.itemSelected = index
```

You can find a more complete explanation here:
[Swift closures causing strong retain cycle with self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261303/swift-closures-causing-strong-retain-cycle-with-self)

Code review: another implementation of the closure can be:

```
  let closure = { [weak self, weak alertList] alert in
        guard let self = self, let alertList = alertList, let index = alertList.actions.index(of: alert) else { 
            return
        }               
        self.itemSelected = index
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the code but it still shows a memory leak.. hm

Comment: My mistake, there can also be a retain cycle between `alertList` and the closure. I corrected the code.